# How to set a bean property of an injected CDI bean from the contains Bean?

Tags: jsf, cdi, managed-bean

I have a CDI Bean which is injected to another CDI bean,

**Bean1Controller:**

```
@ViewScoped
public class bean1Controller
{
    @Inject
    Bean2Controller bean2;
    // + setter and getter

    // here I  initialise the injected Bean2
    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
      bean2 = new Bean2Controller();
    }

 public void changeFlagBoolean()
 {
    bean2.setFlag(true);
 }

}
```

**Bean2Controller:**

```
 @ViewScoped
    public class bean2Controller
    {
       boolean flag=false;
       // + getters+setters
    }
```

**XHTML sample:**

```
<h:commandLink style="font-size: 10px" 
               value="link"
               action="#{bean1Controller.changeFlagBoolean()}"
               target="content" />
```

I have a link in my XHTML Page when I click It I run the method changeFlagBoolean() of bean1Controller **to set the property flag to true of the injected bean2Controller**. I proceed like That but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Any suggestion or something needs to be change in the code. 
Thank you

Comment: Hi, How can we suggest something if the xhtml is not visible? [mcve] please (and version info)

Comment: edited !!
thank you

Comment: Thanks. Version info is still missing and this is not a real [mcve], but close. And 'does not work' is not very helpful analysis. More an end-user description instead of a developer one. And does it work if you remove the target attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Updated Answear,

I got the solution after such research,

The problem was from the `@viewScoped` scope, I couldn't change the value of the flag property in the injected bean and it still always false after doing  `bean2.setFlag(true);`
the problem if I go from `view1.xhtml` to `view2.xhtml` I have a new instance of the `bean1Controller` thats why I have always false as a value because it is a view Scope based.

The olution was with the Flash [https://memorynotfound.com/passing-variables-in-jsf-flash-scope/](http://Link) .  I keep the value in a flash and set its value as ' true' and I called it in the bean2Controller so that it is available in the bean1Controller and get it by callling         `flag = (boolean)flash.get("flag");`

Comment: In your code - `bean2 = new Bean2Controller();` - means `Bean2Controller` is not a CDI bean. If you want it to be CDI, you need to let CDi container handle the creation (e.g. avoid using `new` and let the `@Inject` weave its magic).